# ¿Cómo suluciono este error: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))?

Tags: java, d3.js

Debo hacer un grafico con la librería D3 de Java Script, particularmente, un gráfico del tipo Radial stacked bar chart y estoy editando el código desde la página Observable, en la galería de D3.
En primera instancia, tuve problemas con ingresar los datos desde el archivo CSV, pero cuando finalmente lo logre, me arrojo el error en la linea Const uniqueData, que originalmente era para definir la variable Data, pero me arrojaba el error de Duplicate key, por lo que defini uniqueDato y le hice los ajustes correspondientes, pero ahora tengo este error y no entiendo por que. Le agregue console.log en algunas partes siguiendo la sugerencia del asistente de la misma página, pero no entiendo para que sirve y cuando corri el codigo, no hizo ninguna dferencia, por lo que sigo atascada y no entiendo como puedo solucionarlo.

```
chart = {
  const width = 928;
  const height = width;
  const innerRadius = 180;
  const outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  const uniqueData = Array.from(new Set(data.map(d => d.comuna)), comuna => data.find(d => d.comuna === comuna));
  console.log(uniqueData);
  const series = d3.stack()
      .keys(d3.union(uniqueData.map(d => { console.log(d.tipo); return d.tipo; })))
      .value(([, D], key) => D.get(key).cantidad)
    (d3.index(uniqueData, d => { console.log(d.comuna, d.tipo); return d.comuna; }, d => d.tipo));
  console.log(series);

  const arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(d => y(d[0]))
      .outerRadius(d => y(d[1]))
      .startAngle(d => x(d.uniqueData[0]))
      .endAngle(d => x(d.uniqueData[0]) + x.bandwidth())
      .padAngle(1.5 / innerRadius)
      .padRadius(innerRadius);

  // An angular x-scale
  const x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(d => d.Comuna))
      .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
      .align(0);

  // A radial y-scale maintains area proportionality of radial bars
  const y = d3.scaleRadial()
      .domain([0, d3.max(series, d => d3.max(d, d => d[1]))])
      .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(series.map(d => { console.log(d.key); return d.key; }))
      .range(d3.schemeSpectral[series.length])
      .unknown("#ccc");

  // A function to format the value in the tooltip
  const formatValue = x => isNaN(x) ? "N/A" : x.toLocaleString("en")

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
      .attr("style", "width: 100%; height: auto; font: 10px sans-serif;");

  // A group for each series, and a rect for each element in the series
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll()
    .data(series)
    .join("g")
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.key))
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(D => D.map(d => (d.key = D.key, d)))
    .join("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
    .append("title")
      .text(d => `${d.uniqueData[0]} ${d.key}\n${formatValue(d.uniqueData[1].get(d.key).Cantidad)}`);

  // x axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .selectAll()
    .data(x.domain())
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `
        rotate(${((x(d) + x.bandwidth() / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90)})
        translate(${innerRadius},0)
      `)
      .call(g => g.append("line")
          .attr("x2", -5)
          .attr("stroke", "#000"))
      .call(g => g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", d => (x(d) + x.bandwidth() / 2 + Math.PI / 2) % (2 * Math.PI) < Math.PI
              ? "rotate(90)translate(0,16)"
              : "rotate(-90)translate(0,-9)")
          .text(d => d));

  // y axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .call(g => g.append("text")
          .attr("y", d => -y(y.ticks(5).pop()))
          .attr("dy", "-1em")
          .text("Cantidad"))
      .call(g => g.selectAll("g")
        .data(y.ticks(5).slice(1))
        .join("g")
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .call(g => g.append("circle")
              .attr("stroke", "#000")
              .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
              .attr("r", y))
          .call(g => g.append("text")
              .attr("y", d => -y(d))
              .attr("dy", "0.35em")
              .attr("stroke", "#fff")
              .attr("stroke-width", 5)
              .text(y.tickFormat(5, "s"))
           .clone(true)
              .attr("fill", "#000")
              .attr("stroke", "none")));

  // color legend
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll()
    .data(color.domain())
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", (d, i, nodes) => `translate(-40,${(nodes.length / 2 - i - 1) * 20})`)
      .call(g => g.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .attr("fill", color))
      .call(g => g.append("text")
          .attr("x", 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .text(d => d));

  return svg.node();
}
```

Comment: [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) es para que te muestre los errores en consola. ¿Estás abriendo la consola del navegador?

Comment: No lo sé la verdad, ejecuto el código desde la misma página donde edito el gráfico.

Comment: Entonces buscá cómo abrir la consola del navegador. Te estás perdiendo de una herramienta fundamental para depurar tu código.